# Same SQL query is giving different results in PL SQL developer

Tags: database, plsqldeveloper

I am running a select query in PL SQL developer.
I am not able to figure out that why it is giving different results on execution.
Its not frequent but it happens like after10-20 executions or so.
The reults keep on varying between 5172, 5173 and 5174.
It should be 5172 each time but dont know why it is giving 5173 and 5174 also.
Need your expertise.
Please help me.

My query :
**

> select lounge_station_cd,
>          carrier_cd,
>          lngMst.lounge_cd,
>          lngMst.lounge_name,
>          lngMst.lounge_id,
>          SUM(CASE
>                WHEN customer_type IN ('M', 'F', 'A') THEN
>                 1
>                ELSE
>                 0
>              END) adult_count,
>          SUM(CASE
>                WHEN customer_type IN ('C') THEN
>                 1
>                ELSE
>                 0
>              END) child_count,
>          SUM(CASE
>                WHEN customer_type IN ('M', 'F', 'A', 'C') THEN
>                 1
>                ELSE
>                 0
>              END) total_count   from (select reg_id,
>                  regd_datt,
>                  case
>                    when exit_datt is null then
>                     null
>                    when exit_datt > to_date('01MAR2017 0000', 'ddMONRRRR HH24MI') then
>                     null
>                    else
>                     exit_datt
>                  end exit_datt,
>                  FLT_NUMBER,
>                  GATE,
>                  FLT_ETD_DATT,
>                  carrier_cd,
>                  lounge_station_cd,
>                  tier,
>                  customer_type,
>                  (select pax_dtl_serno
>                     from (select pax_dtl_serno
>                             from lesa_pax_lounge_regn_txn_dtl d
>                            where d.reg_id = a.reg_id
>                              and d.entry_datt BETWEEN
>                                  to_date('01MAR2017 0000', 'ddMONRRRR HH24MI') AND
>                                  to_date('31MAR2017 2359', 'ddMONRRRR HH24MI')
>                              and in_out = 'I'
>                            order by entry_datt desc)
>                    where rownum = 1) entry_id
>             from lesa_pax_lounge_regn_txn a
>            where regd_datt BETWEEN to_date('01MAR2017 0000', 'ddMONRRRR HH24MI') AND
>                  to_date('31MAR2017 2359', 'ddMONRRRR HH24MI')) txn,
>          lesa_pax_lounge_regn_txn_dtl lngdtl,
>          lesa_lounge_mst lngMst  where lngdtl.pax_dtl_serno = txn.entry_id    and lngdtl.reg_id = txn.reg_id    and lngMst.lounge_id
>   = lngdtl.lounge_id    and lngMst.stat_cd in ('DEL')  group by lounge_station_cd,
>             carrier_cd,
>             lounge_cd,
>             lngMst.lounge_id,
>             lounge_name  order by lounge_station_cd, lounge_name, carrier_cd asc

**

Comment: Is the underlying data changing?

Comment: Hi, No nothing as such. The inputs are fromDate, toDate and Station name which are fixed. The date range is one month i.e. from "01MAR2017 0000"  to "31MAR2017 2359" and station is "DEL". All inputs have fixed value but still the count varies for 'adult_count' as 5062 or 5063 or 5064 and because of this the 'total_count' also varies as 5172 or 5173 or 5174. Please provide assistance in this.